# How to display list values of JSON attribute using groovy script in soap ui

Tags: json, soapui, data-driven-tests, data-driven

I have the following json,

```
"Location": "abc",
"Codes":    
[
  {
    "high": "xyz",
    "low": "aaa"
  }
]
```

I am doing Data driven testing using SOAP UI. In the above code I am displaying the "Location" attribute json value in groovy script by using  below code

```
def jsonRes = slurper.parseText(responseJson)
def String LocationJson = jsonRes.Location
log.info ("location is " +LocationJson)
```

Can anyone suggest me how I display the json values of "high" and "low"  which inside "Codes" List?

Answer (score 0):

The "[" and "]" are used to create arrays. So you will need to use a [0] to access the first element of that array. Or use a loop structure, that lets you work directly on each element of the array, like I've done in the example below.

I modified your code. I hope you are able to run it without modifications.

```
def jsonstring = '{"Location": "abc","Codes": [ { "high": "xyz", "low": "aaa" } ] }"'
log.info jsonstring
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def jsonRes = slurper.parseText(jsonstring)
def LocationJson = jsonRes.Location
log.info ("location is " +LocationJson)

// this will loop through all Codes element...
for (def codeElement : jsonRes.Codes) {
    log.info ("high is " + codeElement.high)
    log.info ("low is " + codeElement.low)  
}
```

Comment: ...if you don't need to loop, and would like to just access the elements directly, this can be achieved with jsonRes.Codes[0].high